# Why does adding ORDER BY drastically speed up query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, query-performance, sql-limit

I've discovered some very strange and counter-intuitive behaviour in PostgreSQL.

I have a query structure as follows. I am selecting both the IDs and the count from a subquery. The subquery does the filtering, joining, counting, but only orders by the IDs, since I'm using DISTINCT ON() to only get unique IDs.

The outer query then does the proper ordering, and any limits and offsets as needed. Here is an example of what the query structure looks like:

```
SELECT s.id, s.item_count
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (work_items.id) work_items.id
        , work_item_states.disposition AS disposition
        , COUNT(work_items.id) OVER () AS item_count
    FROM work_items
    JOIN work_item_states ON work_item_states.work_item_refer = work_items.id
    WHERE work_item_states.disposition = 'cancelled'
    ORDER BY work_items.id
) AS s
ORDER BY s.disposition
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

I've discovered something strange however. My database has several million entries, so overall queries aren't the fastest. But when I remove the ORDER BY clause in the **OUTER** query, it drastically slows down the query time.

However, if I also remove the LIMIT clause, it becomes fast again, despite the fact that this example query is returning 800 000+ results.

In summary, for the outer query:

**ORDER BY** AND **LIMIT** - Fast

```
...
) AS s
ORDER BY s.disposition
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

ONLY **LIMIT** - Very slow

```
...
) AS s
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

ONLY **ORDER BY** - Fast, despite 800 000 results

```
...
) AS s
ORDER BY s.disposition
OFFSET 0
```

NEITHER - Fast, despite 800 000 results

```
...
) AS s
OFFSET 0
```

To give an idea of how much slower only having the LIMIT clause is, with both, neither, or just ORDER BY, the queries take no more than about 10 seconds.

With only the LIMIT clause however, the queries take about a minute 15, over 7 times as long!

You'd think that ORDER BY would instead slow things down, as it has to sort the results of the subquery, but it seems that isn't the case. It's very counter-intuitive.

If someone knows what's going on behind the scenes here, I'd greatly appreciate them shedding some light on this.

Thanks

**EDIT** - Added execution plans for statements:

**ORDER BY and LIMIT execution plan**

```
Limit  (cost=518486.52..518486.65 rows=50 width=53)
  ->  Sort  (cost=518486.52..520495.59 rows=803628 width=53)
        Sort Key: s.disposition
        ->  Subquery Scan on s  (cost=479736.16..491790.58 rows=803628 width=53)
              ->  Unique  (cost=479736.16..483754.30 rows=803628 width=53)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=479736.16..481745.23 rows=803628 width=53)
                          Sort Key: work_items.id
                          ->  WindowAgg  (cost=136262.98..345979.65 rows=803628 width=53)
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=136262.98..335934.30 rows=803628 width=45)
                                      Hash Cond: (work_items.id = work_item_states.work_item_refer)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on work_items  (cost=0.00..106679.48 rows=4020148 width=37)
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=119152.97..119152.97 rows=803681 width=45)
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on work_item_states  (cost=18968.96..119152.97 rows=803681 width=45)
                                                  Recheck Cond: (disposition = 'cancelled'::text)
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_work_item_states_disposition  (cost=0.00..18768.04 rows=803681 width=0)
                                                        Index Cond: (disposition = 'cancelled'::text)
```

**Only LIMIT execution plan**

```
Limit  (cost=1.11..69.52 rows=50 width=45)
  ->  Subquery Scan on s  (cost=1.11..1099599.17 rows=803628 width=45)
        ->  Unique  (cost=1.11..1091562.89 rows=803628 width=77)
              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1.11..1089553.82 rows=803628 width=77)
                    ->  Merge Join  (cost=1.11..1079508.47 rows=803628 width=37)
                          Merge Cond: (work_items.id = work_item_states.work_item_refer)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using idx_work_items_id on work_items  (cost=0.56..477365.14 rows=4020148 width=37)
                          ->  Index Scan using idx_work_item_states_work_item_refer on work_item_states  (cost=0.56..582047.48 rows=803681 width=37)
                                Filter: (disposition = 'cancelled'::text)
```

**Only ORDER BY execution plan**

```
Sort  (cost=625547.09..627556.16 rows=803628 width=53)
  Sort Key: s.disposition
  ->  Subquery Scan on s  (cost=479736.16..491790.58 rows=803628 width=53)
        ->  Unique  (cost=479736.16..483754.30 rows=803628 width=53)
              ->  Sort  (cost=479736.16..481745.23 rows=803628 width=53)
                    Sort Key: work_items.id
                    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=136262.98..345979.65 rows=803628 width=53)
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=136262.98..335934.30 rows=803628 width=45)
                                Hash Cond: (work_items.id = work_item_states.work_item_refer)
                                ->  Seq Scan on work_items  (cost=0.00..106679.48 rows=4020148 width=37)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=119152.97..119152.97 rows=803681 width=45)
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on work_item_states  (cost=18968.96..119152.97 rows=803681 width=45)
                                            Recheck Cond: (disposition = 'cancelled'::text)
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_work_item_states_disposition  (cost=0.00..18768.04 rows=803681 width=0)
                                                  Index Cond: (disposition = 'cancelled'::text)
```

Comment: You should post execution plans for all 3 cases.

Comment: Is that done by using EXPLAIN?

Comment: the plans should be generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` and please add them as text, not as screenshots. Or upload them to http://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: Updated with execution plans. Didn't see the `explain (analyze, buffers)` till after editing. Is that enough, or do you need the buffers too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't post your execution plans, but I have my crystal ball ready, so I'll have a guess at what's going on.

In your second, very slow query the optimizer has a bright idea how to make it fast:
It scans `work_items` using the index on `id`, fetches all the matching rows from `work_item_states` in a nested loop and filters out everything that does not match `work_item_states.disposition = 'cancelled'` until it has found 50 distinct result.

This is a good idea, but the optimizer does not know that all the rows with `work_item_states.disposition = 'cancelled'` match `work_items` with a high `id`, so it has to scan forever until it has found its 50 rows.

All the other queries don't allow the planner to choose that strategy because it is only promising if a few rows in `work_items.id` order will do.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I did update the post with the execution plans now however.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Know of any way of working around this? Not the end of the world if it's too much of a hassle. I can just set a default order by in my program if needed.

Comment: Either keep an additional `ORDER BY` clause if it doesn't hurt, or put an `OFFSET 0` in the inner query.

Comment: Did try putting the OFFSET 0 in the inner query. Didn't seem to make a difference: https://explain.depesz.com/s/TpGm

Comment: Duh, my bad. Seem to have lost my crystal ball. Then stick with the superfluous `ORDER BY`.

Comment: just FYI: query optimization algorithm implemented in `postgresql` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/geqo-pg-intro.html)

Comment: @Moshii That's only the "genetic query optimizer", a heuristic component that is used for queries over more than 15 tables. It has nothing to do with the problem at hand.